# Empty attachment when exporting to Gmail

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

Users have recently started to report an issue when sharing files from my Android app using Gmail. The attachment is received empty by the recipient. I've never been able to reproduce on my devices but they've sent me such emails and I've seen the empty attachment.

This seems to happen exclusively on **Android 7 and above**.

Here is the way I share a file in my app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName(activityInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@domain.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getFileProviderAuthority(), textFile);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
context.grantUriPermission(activityInfo.packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

For now, I haven't been able to understand why it happens for some users and not others. Most of them seem to have the latest version of Gmail.

One thing I noticed is that when I have a look at the original email I receive from these users, the ones from problematic users look like this:

```
----_com.android.email_1901922805148181 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

*encoded email body*

----_com.android.email_1901922805148181  
Content-Type: text/plain;  name="filename.txt"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="filename.txt";  size=262
----_com.android.email_1901922805148181--
```

And the ones from regular users look like this:

```
--001a1145af74a967fe0566ff756c 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

*email body*

--001a1145af74a967fe0566ff756c--
--001a1145af74a968010566ff756e 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"; name="log.txt" 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="log.txt" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-ID: <1620c22fd58144d0cc61> X-Attachment-Id: 1620c22fd58144d0cc61

*encoded attachment*

--001a1145af74a968010566ff756e--
```

## Update

We've been able to reproduce this issue from any app that can share files via an `ACTION_SEND` intent, choosing Gmail and **using an non-Google email account** instead (ie not Gmail email address).

A necessary condition to reproduce is to **add some text in the email body** manually before sending the email (it's not enough to have some text in the intent `EXTRA_TEXT`). Without adding text, the attachment is sent correctly. With text, it cannot be opened by the receiver.

Comment: Make sure you've done those steps: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html

Comment: Yes, I've specified a file provider

Comment: Dont know if it is the cause but `context.grantUriPermission(activityInfo.packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` is pretty strange. I would use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
` instead.
`

Comment: This is what the Android documentation recommends: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions

Comment: Can be. Just try it out! You do not know what to do else are you? I have not such problems.

Comment: Thanks for filing this, we're seeing this too

Comment: We've been completely unable to reproduce this, even with an IMAP account, do you have any other insights? We'd really like to be able to repro it.

Comment: Use Android 7, set up a Yahoo or Outlook account in Settings accounts and remove all Google accounts on the device. Export a file from any app to Gmail, add some text in body and send. Feel free to send me a video if it still doesn't work to see if I'm missing something :)

Comment: Thanks, we'll try that!  Did you find a solution or work around?  It'd be a big help if you could email me, alex at invoicesimple dot com

Comment: Thanks Guilaumme, we've now been able to repro it, phew.  Seems like it must be a gmail bug eh?  Not sure if there is a work around or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this bug has been fixed in the latest version of Gmail for Android: 8.3.12.190852125